# Styling DataGridCell Error Template

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I would like the TextBox on my TextBoxDataGridColumn to display a red background when the cell value is invalid. I haven't been able to get rid of the annoying default red border.

How to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add this style to your Control resources, it should work for all the textboxes in your control then -

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type TextBox}" TargetType="TextBox">
  <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate>
        <Border Background="Red" Opacity="0.5" ToolTip="{Binding ElementName=adorner,Path=AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}">
           <AdornedElementPlaceholder Name="adorner"/>
        </Border>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score -1):

http://japikse.blogspot.com/2009/07/idataerrorinfo-error-templates-and-wpf.html

some ideas there, is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Please do not post links without further content as answer. The link is now broken, your answer useless.